# Parallelize column pairwise matrix comparison

Tags: r, foreach

For a given matrix named `db.mtx.rnk` I'm calculating column pairwise kendall and spearman correlations and saving the results into a squared matrix. The problem is that input matrix is quite big (~5000x5000) and the number of pairwise combinations are too high which takes long time to perform. One option to reduce time by half would be to only calculate the upper triangle, which I have not implemented it yet, but still would be slow. I would like to parallelize to get results. Any hint?

Current code:

```
# -- get pairwise column combinations
pairwise.permuts <- t(expand.grid(1:ncol(db.mtx.rnk), 1:ncol(db.mtx.rnk)))

# -- iterate over two stats of interest   
for(stat in c("kendall", "spearman")){

      # -- kendall tau and spearman 
      stats.vec <- apply(pairwise.permuts, 2, function(x) cor(db.mtx.rnk[,x[1]], db.mtx.rnk[,x[2]], method = stat))
      stats.mtx <- matrix(stats.vec, ncol = ncol(db.mtx.rnk))
      colnames(stats.mtx) <- colnames(db.mtx.rnk)
      rownames(stats.mtx) <- colnames(db.mtx.rnk)
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different possibilities how to parallelise in R. Some options are [`parallel`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf), [`foreach`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.html) and [`future`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future). Given your code, the least changes you have to make with the `future` based package [`future.apply`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.apply) as it provides the function `future_apply`. You have to use `plan(multiprocess)` to tell `future` that it should be calculated in parallel. `multiprocess` uses different R sessions or forking depending on your OS. This leads to the code (and already speeds up a toy example on my machine):

```
library(future.apply)
plan(multiprocess)
for(stat in c("kendall", "spearman")){

  # -- kendall tau and spearman 
  stats.vec <- future_apply(pairwise.permuts, 2, function(x) cor(db.mtx.rnk[,x[1]], db.mtx.rnk[,x[2]], method = stat))
  stats.mtx <- matrix(stats.vec, ncol = ncol(db.mtx.rnk))
  colnames(stats.mtx) <- colnames(db.mtx.rnk)
  rownames(stats.mtx) <- colnames(db.mtx.rnk)
}
```

Comment: I've tried a reduced version of the matrix (10 columns) with ```future_apply```using different plan:  ```multicore```, ```multiproces``` and ```multisesion```and non of them improve ``apply```.
Not at least in a MacOS

Comment: How long does your reduced version of the matrix takes? Usually, you'll see improvements only when the data is large enough, because the parallelisation also introduces some overhead. My toy example went from 16 min to 6 min (`test_mat <- matrix(rnorm(250000), nrow = 500, ncol = 500)`).

Comment: 362 seconds with apply, 382 with ```future_apply plan(multiporcess)```

Comment: That's maybe too short to notice a difference. Maybe try an example that takes at least 10 min serially and then compare it to the parallelised version. Do you use RStudio? There, `multicore` doesn't work, you would need to run it directly with R.

Comment: Ok, yes I'm using it with Rstudio, I was wondering if that could be a reason.
I'll try the way you suggested.

Comment: But `multisession` should also work in RStudio, so I'm not completely sure what could be the issue.

Comment: It seems that runnning ```future_apply```with ```plan(multiprocess)```with ```Rscript```reduces the time.  But ```multisesion```in rstudio does not

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the observation! I realised you made a typo in `multisesion`. Have you used the correct `multisession` for your experiments?

Comment: Yes I used ```plan("multisession")```with Rstudio.

Comment: Finally I used ```cor.fk()``` for kendall which is pretty fast and ```cor()```which calculates spearman fastly too.